# Why is "2012-30-03" parsed as June 3 2014 with DateFormat?

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a string (ex: 2012-30-03 12:30), and I am trying to use the following code:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
this.startTime = (Date) df.parse(startTime); // startTime = "2012-30-03 12:30"
```

But when I try the following:

```
System.out.println(this.startTime);
```

The following get printed

> Tue Jun 03 12:30:00 CEST 2014

What the heck is wrong here?

Is there a better way to turn the kind of string I have into a working date object?

Comment: Pretty much across the board I use joda time:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Please take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). Specifically [this section](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output)

Comment: While there should arguably be an exception raised, it is "technically correct" if one goes ***30 months** and **3 days** past 2012*. In any case, please try to write questions in a more objective form.

Comment: Writing down the date correctly -- how does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

should be

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm");`

based on the example string you provided (`2012-30-03 12:30`).

Focus your rage against the date class into verifying the basics and you'll be ok. ;)

Comment: It's probably the example string that's wrong. No one uses a year-day-month format. It's either year-month-day, month-day-year, or day-month-year.

Comment: possibly, but I can only diagnose based on the information as written.  Also, I've seen weirder things in software other than a non-standard date format.

Comment: I can hear the facepalm from here ;)